# Supervisor ошибка Too many open files to spawn 'worker_name'

Tags: linux, ubuntu

В конфиге supervisor'а:

```
[program:worker]
command=php /root/worker_test/RPCServerWorker.php
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
autostart=true
autorestart=true
;user=root
stopsignal=KILL
numprocs=650
stdout_logfile=/root/worker_test/worker_stdout.log
```

Успешно запускается только 150 воркеров, на остальных пишется ошибка в лог. При этом веб интерфейс становится не доступным.
Если указать например `numprocs=150`, то все работает.

Как исправить ошибку?

**UPD**

Заметил что запускается 151 воркер (при указанном numprocs=650), при этом веб морда не доступна (bad gateway | timeout). Затем убиваю одного воркера и веб морда становится доступной. Завершенный мною процесс supervisor не восстанавливает.

Увеличил все лимиты системы, ничего не помогает.

Comment: minfds=64000 или другое подходящее число.

Comment: Пробовал, ставил 4096. Supervisor запустил около 3000 воркеров (потом кончилась память). Веб интерфейс все также был недоступен.

Comment: ну так numprocs поставьте в 2000. Или Вы хотите запускать миллиарды воркеров?

Comment: Зачем numprocs ставить в 2000? Мне нужно 650 воркеров.

Comment: а как же тогда запустилось 3000... Если выставлено 650.

Comment: В этом то и проблема, настройки были как в моем вопросе + minfds=4096 в секции supervisord. При этом с numprocs=150 все правильно запускается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась установкой Supervisor'a версии 3.3.3 в котором решена данная проблема. Извиняюсь за запоздалый фидбек.